# What's the purpose of the Reversal badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

No one has ever been awarded this badge, what is the purpose of having it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have 10k reputation, you can have a look at [this deleted question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14936/cant-connect-to-wireless-access-point-after-installing-proprietary-drivers/14983#14983). If you don't, here are the headlines:

- The question was in a terrible state, and it got `-12` as a consequence:

  > ### Just read details
  >
  > I had windows vista basic i replaced it {completely} using ubuntu 10.10 disk
  >
  > I downloaded the wireless driver from aditional drivers
  >
  > I enabled wireless
  >
  > It wont read my router my game systems will so...
  >
  > [...]
- Everyone worked fairly hard to turn it into a good question
- I provided a huge answer, which got `+13` — Oh, so close!

The Reversal badge motivated me to write a big general guide about this strange, non-reproducible problem. Effectively turning it from "I have this weird problem with my wireless network" into "What do I do if I have *any* problems with wireless networks".

Terrible questions that can be turned into great resources are few and far between. But when they turn up, there's a badge to make sure someone is motivated to save it, in case it can be saved. Even if that badge seems impossibly hard to get.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me. But, why was the question deleted?

Comment: I don't know, really. From the UI, it looks like either I deleted it myself (which I don't remember) or the system deleted it automatically. But the question is not *that* on-topic, and it's not extremely useful either, so that's fine. I'll add an excerpt of the question to this answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I don't have 10k reputation.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo A question is never automatically deleted if it has positive-score answers (in fact, it's never automatically deleted if it has any answers IIRC). If you feel your answer is worthwhile, please undelete it (or ask a fellow mod if you dislike the conflict of interest).

Answer (score 2):

No one has ever been awarded this badge on Ask Ubuntu. But, for example on [stack **overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) this badge has been awarded 143 times. So, there are possibilities to have it.